# Problem regarding the speed of two points $A$ and $B$ moving with constant speed in the plane

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, contest-math, coordinate-systems

Consider a Point A that moves linearly on the positive x-axis with the speed 1 m/s and another Point B at a distance L from A with position (L,0). With each forward motion of point A the Point B moves in an arc consistently maintaining the distance L from point A. As soon as Point A reaches x=L, the Point B is perpendicular to Point A and its position is (L,L). Both the points move at a constant speed.

How then do you determine the speed of B?

Note that in this problem I considered the Center of Mass of the objects as points.

**Is it possible to determine the equation of the curve that point B traces and its arc length? If yes, then how?**

Comment: Ken. Please don't keep reposting the same question. Also do not delete the old versions. You are denying the answerers of the older versions the change to earn the reputation they deserve for helping you out. This is the rule here.